# How to debug a broken Google Play store?

Tags: google-play-store

I can´t use the Google Play store. I open it and it freezes on the loading animation. How can I debug it to know whats happening? I have free space on flash, I've been erasing lots of apps and documents in case that was the problem, but nothing. What can I do? This is critical as my job VPN access and bank depend on my android, I need the play store to work.

I have android 9 on a ZTE A7

EDIT: Already tried also deleting Google Play Store and Google Services data, but still not working

Comment: @alecxs I was not able to uninstall the updates of the application, I didn't found the option. I'm connected to wifi, but I've tried connected to 4g and same error occured. The device is stock with official firmware, and I have no firewall app installed.

Comment: Is it really broken, or just appears so? Is your network a factor? My phone/network tries to enumerate some IPv6 WiFi connections, but does so slowly, so I have turned off ipv6 functionality to restore speed over function. This may have been transitory, but I haven't returned to it.

Comment: @wbogacz tbh I wouldn't be able to tell the difference between broken or appears to be. My wifi connection never presented issues, in fact I can use all other apps (instagram, reddit, whatsapp, etc) with no problem. I will try the ipv6 trick

Comment: Hm.. what else you could try? remove all google accounts. or try to uninstall google play (+ services) from adb shell (at least updates). try older version from apkmirror, apkpure, etc